# Access "People " album and getting images from it

Tags: swift, photosframework

im developing an iOS application which I need to import to my app, some images from the library, especially the "People" album images, I need them to be displayed, but I'm not able to access this album, I tried the code below:

```
  func FetchCustomAlbumPhotos()
    {
        let albumName = "People"
        var assetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
        var albumFound = Bool()
        var photoAssets = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
        let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
        if let _:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
            //found the album
            assetCollection = collection.firstObject!
            albumFound = true
        }
        else { albumFound = false }
        _ = collection.count
        photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

        //        let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

        photoAssets.enumerateObjects{(object: AnyObject!,
            count: Int,
            stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

            if object is PHAsset{
                let asset = object as! PHAsset
                print("Inside  If object is PHAsset, This is number 1")
                let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,
                                       height: asset.pixelHeight)

                /* For faster performance, and maybe degraded image */
                let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
                options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
                options.isSynchronous = true
                imageManager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                          targetSize: imageSize,
                                          contentMode: .aspectFit ,
                                          options: options,
                                          resultHandler: {
                                            (image, info) -> Void in
                                            print("Image \(String(describing: image))")
                                            self.addImgToArray(uploadImage: image!)
                                            //self.photo = image!
                                            /* The image is now available to us */
                                            //self.addImgToArray(self.photo)
                                            print("enum for image, This is number 2")

                })
            }
        }
    }
```

if I created an album and called it "test", I'm able to fetch it, but I'm not able to fetch any built in album like "People" which I need.
any help?

Comment: could you please provide the link of the duplicated question?

Comment: The duplicated question _is_ a link. See it? Above your question???

Answer (score 1):

First: You should *not* be attempting to access an album by title in any case; I do it when I'm being lazy, but the user can change the title of a user album, so it's unreliable. You should use the identifier.

Second: To access a built-in smart album, use the `smartAlbum` type and set the subtype appropriately, as @rmaddy rightly suggested.

Third: But that won't work for the People album. You can't access it at all.

I'm pretty sure the inability to access the People album is a bug, as reported here:

http://www.openradar.me/29797672

Of course I suppose it *might* be hidden from you on purpose; I don't know. But I'm afraid you'll have to do without that feature.

Comment: could you please explain how to set the subtype?? its unclear